# Jasmine error while running protractor test through tfs

Tags: visual-studio-2015, protractor, jasmine2.0

I am trying to run protractor through tfs from a sln my local dev dept made.  I am able to successfully run these tests locally and through eclipse however when I use the test the vs test explorer I get the below error

```
ReferenceError: browser is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:62225/Tests.js:4:9)
at attemptSync (http://localhost:62225/jasmine_2._4.jasmine.js:1886:24)
at QueueRunner.run (http://localhost:62225/jasmine_2._4.jasmine.js:1874:9)
at QueueRunner.execute (http://localhost:62225/jasmine_2._4.jasmine.js:1859:10)
at Spec.queueRunnerFactory (http://localhost:62225/jasmine_2._4.jasmine.js:697:35)
at Spec.execute (http://localhost:62225/jasmine_2._4.jasmine.js:359:10)
at Object.fn (http://localhost:62225/jasmine_2._4.jasmine.js:2479:37)
at attemptAsync (http://localhost:62225/jasmine_2._4.jasmine.js:1916:24)
at QueueRunner.run (http://localhost:62225/jasmine_2._4.jasmine.js:1871:9)
at QueueRunner.execute (http://localhost:62225/jasmine_2._4.jasmine.js:1859:10)
```

I tried to look at the jasmine.js file however I have no idea what I am looking at.  The dev who has it successfully running has all the same versions of webdriver, protactor, jasmine, etc.  Any idea what this could be?

Comment: I am assuming that `jasmine_2._4.jasmine.js` means that you are running jasmine 2.4? The latest version of Protractor uses `jasmine@^2.5.3`.

Comment: @cnishina No I have 2.6 installed